# Why the step $\sum\limits_n n^{-s}=\sum\limits_n n(n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s})$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I don't quite follows this step on a proof:

$$\sum_n n^{-s}=\sum_n n(n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s})$$

I'm sure it's quite simple, but I'm afraid I don't see it.

Comment: $$n^{-s}=(n-(n-1))n^{-s}=nn^{-s}-(n-1)n^{-s}=nn^{-s}-k(k+1)^{-s}\quad k=n-1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\text{Re}(s)>1$. By using [Abel's summation by parts](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Summation_by_Parts),
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N f_n(g_{n+1}-g_n) = \left(f_{N+1}g_{N+1} - f_1 g_1\right) - \sum_{n=1}^N g_{n+1}(f_{n+1}- f_n)
$$ applied to $f_n=n$, $g_n=\dfrac1{n^s}$, one gets
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N n\left(\frac1{(n+1)^s}-\frac1{n^s}\right) &= \left[(N+1)\frac1{(N+1)^s} - 1\right] - \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{(n+1)^s}
\\\\&=\frac1{(N+1)^{s-1}}-\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac1{n^s}
\end{align}
$$ then, by letting $N \to \infty$, one obtains

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac1{n^s}-\frac1{(n+1)^s}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^s}=\zeta(s),\qquad \text{Re}(s)>1,
> $$

as announced.

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I needed. Just a quick question: are the order of the terms correct? After applying Abel's summation we have $-\zeta(s)$ on the right, and the terms on the reverse order on the left. It's also very likely that I'm just mistaken.